# Can the application restart automaticly after it coredown?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Sometimes the erlang application will coredown by out of memery or other reasons.
Can I config something to let it restart when it coredown?

Comment: can you rephrase your question and add some relevant error output? It is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: My question is I am afraid of my erlang appliction coredown by some reasons like out of memery, in that case, the service of my application will stop. So I need find a way to let my application restart automaticly after it coredown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

erlang support option --heart for monitoring if erlang process still alive. In case of crashing or hanging erlang process, heartbeat part reboots the whole server (it assumes your erlang application starts at booting of your server).  You can read all details here:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/heart.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I still don't know how to make it out after I read the document of heart, would you please give me a example how to config the heart?

Comment: @david.liu Since you have marked this answer as correct you will most likely not get any more answers for this question.  Start another question on how to configure heart for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you all the same, I have config it right in linux os,and now it works well. ^_^